# What does "Britain" have to do with "the destruction of the second Beis HaMikdosh"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, beis-hamikdash, churban-destruction

Abarbanel on Torah, Deuteronomy 28:49, writes

> ["Now he mentions the destruction of the second Beis HaMikdosh. From
> afar. Who came from Britain and other distant countries speedily."](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.49?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)

I only have one question as titled. If the response answers any of the following questions, too, then please bring it to my attention:

Who is the "he" in this quote? To whom does he source "Britain"? Who was the first to mention "Britain" in relation to the destruction of the Temple?

Answer (score 3):

The "he" refers to the speaker, in this case Moses. Abarbanel quotes the book of Yosiphon as saying that some of the troops used by Rome in the destruction of the second Temple came from Britain/England.

Comment: Yes as he says כנזכר בספר יוסיפון. A reference to where Josephus says this would be be most beneficiary.

Comment: @ezra You're welcome to look for it. :-)

Comment: Besides "Britain" are there any list of countries from any Jewish source from where "the troops used by Rome in the destruction of the second Temple came from"?

Comment: @ninamag Abarbanel there writes באו עמים רבים מארצות המערב מברט"נייה ואינגי"לטיר ובר"גונייה ומארצות מזרח גם כן - "Many nations came from the lands of the West, from Brittany(?), England and Burgundy, as well as from the lands of the East"

Comment: @ezra I believe Josippon is a different book. It's based on Josephus but isn't the same work.

Comment: N.T., Abarbanel writes "יוסיפון" as ezra said. Yosifon or Josippon is not Josephus. It's a work probably authored around the time of the Gaonim if I remember correctly and appears to be based on Josehpus's works, though it seems to be an attempt to condense Josephus's writings and to make them a little more in line with Rabbinic thought (which Josephus isn't exactly so). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josippon).

Comment: Not that Brittany or England or Burgundy existed with anything like those names at the destruction of the Second Temple; nor were the Romans yet recruiting in their recent conquests in Armorica or Britannia or near the Rhine.  These were much more plausible place names 9 centuries later when Sefer Yosifon/Josippon was written or 5 centuries after that when Abarbanel was writing.

Comment: I changed it to be more accurate. I assumed that Yosiphon was able to identify Britain based on Josephus's writings, but I admit that was a little lazy.

Comment: I am surprised you did not accept N.T's answer, but to add context, Titus was a commander in the invasion of Britain in 43, and served as Tribune in Britannia around the year 60, and 10 years later he brought about the Chorban.